# Emscripten exported function oddities in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c++, c, visual-studio-2010, emscripten

I'm just starting to play around with Emscripten, but I've run into something odd, when trying to export functions, for use in JavaScript. The test project has to do with libsquish, but it's not really relevant for the question, other than the header/code filenames.

So - anyway, simple test.

**c/c++**

```
//squish.h
extern "C" int main();
int main();

extern "C" int gsr();
int gsr();

//squish.cpp
int main()
{
    return 99;
}

int gsr()
{
    //return squish::GetStorageRequirements(width,height,flags);
    return 8675309;
}
```

**Additional Options/Command Line**

```
-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_gsr','_main']"
```

**Javascript**

```
main=Module.cwrap('main','number',null);
console.log(main());

GetStorageRequirements = Module.cwrap('gsr', 'number',null);
console.log(GetStorageRequirements());
```

**Javascript Console (Chrome)**

```
99
Assertion failed: Cannot call unknown function gsr (perhaps LLVM optimizations or closure removed it?)
Assertion failed: Cannot call unknown function gsr (perhaps LLVM optimizations or closure removed it?)
```

And on top of everything else, optimization is disabled (O0).

So, what's the deal here? Same return types, same number of parameters, defined in exactly the same way, with the only difference being the name of the function. Yet one works, and the other is "unknown".

The only possible, logical cause is that it's automatically exporting main, and ignoring the EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS all together. But if that's the case, I have no idea why.

Comment: Your program is working perfectly for me, printing 99 then 8675309 to the console log in Chrome.  I copied your c++ code above into "squish.cc" and then ran: emcc squish.cc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_gsr','_main']"

Comment: Next I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="a.out.js"></script>` to an html file, as well as your code above in script tags.  Am I doing anything differently from you?

Comment: other than the extension (cpp vs cc), and using visual studio instead of the command line, no. I guess I'll try using the emscripten command line - and see if I get any different results.

Comment: Running it via the command line worked. So, now I know there's something not set up right in vstudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Charles Ofria's work in narrowing down the issue, the only real oddity ended up being with the Emscripten Visual Studio plugin. I was on the right track, when I thought that it might just be automatically exporting main - which was correct. The reason it wasn't exporting the other function, was because I put it in the Additional Options, for the Clang/C++ section, instead of the Emcc Linker.

The trouble was, and this is where the "oddity" comes in, the Emcc Linker section doesn't appear when you choose `Console Application (.js)` as the Configuration Type. So, after changing the Target Extension to `.html` and the Configuration Type to `Browser Application (.html)` - the Linker section re-appeared, and I was able to put the `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS` option, in the correct location.

After building, and copying the output over, both functions were defined, and returned the proper values in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue here is C++ name mangling. That's a C++ filename, so "gsr" turns into something like "_Z3gsr". You can avoid that by making it a C file, or using `extern "C"` around that method.

For more see http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process

Comment: I was under the impression that declaring the method using `extern "C"` and then declaring it outside, as well as defining the method in the .cpp file, would accomplish that. Or is it the case of the second (c++) declaration, compromising it in some way?